Am i scammed? Bought this token named CLASK
I cannot swap from CLASK to bnb when i try from trustwallet im getting this message erc20 transfer amount exceeds balance then when i try to swap it through pancakeswap im getting the transfer from failed message. The token address is this 0x58006e5abF180177EA0cF105d6ffCB6e0695D294

Does this answer your question? I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?

Same situation for me. It extremely probable

When the ERC20 transfer amount exceeds the balance, the transfer operation cannot be completed, and subsequent exchanges cannot be carried out. When receiving a failure message through Pancake swap exchange, there may be various reasons, such as network issues, incorrect transaction parameter settings, abnormal execution of smart contracts, etc.
